# switch theme with SCSS and React

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, frontend, themes

I would like to include different color themes in SCSS from a $palette variable.

I tried a lot of things but being on the backend side, I'm far from being a frontend specialist.

here is the organization of my project

**libs/vars.scss**

```
$palette: (
    bg:                         #313131,
    bg-alt:                     #2e2e2e,
    bg-contrast:                #10101047,
    fg:                         #ececec,
    fg-alt:                     #313131,
    fg-bold:                    #ffffff,
    fg-light:                   #cdcdcd,
    border:                     #e6e6e64d,
    border-bg:                  #c3c3c313,
    border-alt:                 rgba(160,160,160,0.65),
    accent:                     #ffe867,
    accent-2:                   #9e75ff,
    accent-3:                   #30c475,
    accent-4:                   #ec4710,
);
```

**libs/function.scss**

```
@function _palette($keys...) {
    @return val($palette, $keys...);
}
```

example of using a palette value in a component

**composant.scss**

```
.some-class{
    color: _palette(fg);
    border: 1px solid _palette(accent-3);
    background: _palette(fg-bold);
    transition: border .3s ease;
    
    &:focus {
        outline: none;
        border-color: _palette(accent-4);
    }
}
```

I import everything into my **main.scss**

```
@import 'libs/vars';
@import 'libs/mixins';
@import 'libs/skel';
@import 'libs/functions';


// breakpoint
@include skel-breakpoints((
    xlarge: '(max-width: 1680px)',
    large: '(max-width: 1280px)',
    medium: '(max-width: 980px)',
    small: '(max-width: 736px)',
    xsmall: '(max-width: 480px)'
));

@include skel-layout((
    reset: 'full',
    boxModel: 'border',
    grid: ( gutters: 1em )
));

// Base
@import 'base/page';
@import 'base/typo';

// other components ...
```

now what i would like is that with a switch in react, i can define a new color palette to change the theme.

I don't know if this is possible with the SCSS.

```
function App() {

  // theme change

  return (
  <div className='light-theme'>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <OtherComponents>
    </Provider>
  </div>
  );
}
```

What's the best way to do this? I know a little about functions, mixin in SCSS. Can I use this to change the palette color ?

I'm taking over a project, I can't do all the SCSS again. So I'm looking for a solution to switch the color palette easily